# Environment variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Where do the environment variables under Jenkins ( *manage jenkins -> system information* ) come from?

I checked `/etc/init.d/tomcat5`, `/usr/bin/dtomcat5`, `/usr/bin/tomcat5`, `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat5` and `/etc/profile` but do not see any such variables there specially the ones related to Oracle (`Base`, `Home`, `Ld_lib`, `path`, etc.).
Tomcat's `bashrc` has some oracle related variables which I commented out but I still see the same in the jenkins system info page. Any directions?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The environment variables displayed in Jenkins (*Manage Jenkins -> System information*) are inherited from the system (i.e. inherited environment variables)

If you run `env` command in a shell you should see the same environment variables as Jenkins shows.

These variables are either set by the shell/system or by you in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`.

There are also environment variables [set by Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) when a job executes, but these are not displayed in the System Information.

Comment: I have set environment variable for the jenkins account as well as root account for the TZ variable in the ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile of both accounts. The env command in both accounbts lists TZ var setting. But Jenkins /systemInfo page does not show TZ and my unit test which relies on it is failing. What could be wrong?

Comment: @FarrukhNajmi Try setting the environment variable as system wide in [/etc/environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-environment) or source the files where you've added your own variables at the beginning of your build script. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818403/jenkins-hudson-environment-variables

Comment: If you're using Jenkins on Windows and it runs as a system service, then make sure the environment variables are set as system wide ones, not per-user, otherwise Jenkins won't be able to see them.

Comment: Thank you for the Jenkins variables link, do you know if there is another place where it defines more variables? I can't find a variable with the Jenkins user who started the build. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Apparently it is only available through this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin

Comment: they aren't in there.

Answer (score 20):

The quick and dirty way, you can view the available environment variables from the below link.

http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html/

Just replace `localhost` with your Jenkins hostname, if its different

Comment: The URL mentioned works as expected (copy/paste) directly in the browser address bar, but through the GUI of Jenkins itself, in what section and where is the link that refers to that URL?

Answer (score 17):

What ultimately worked for me was the following steps:

1. Configure the [Environment Injector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)
2. Goto to the `/job/<project>/configure screen`
3. In "Build Environment" section check "**Inject environment variables to the build process**"
4. In "Properties Content" specified: `TZ=America/New_York`

Comment: I'm trying to set a variable with a dynamic value. Do you know how to do run a script/batch command in step 4 in order to set the value?

Comment: The EnvInject Plugin allows you to prepare the environment using a shell script either by referencing a script file (see Script File Path) or by including its content (see Script Content). I would appreciate an up vote and marking this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I did that but how do you access TZ in your bash script? `loc=${TZ}` or `loc=${env.TZ}` doesn't work