# How can I use a linux system variable in my Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins

I want to use a curl with a username and password that I set in the bashrc.  ie:

```
curl -u $jenkuser:$jenkpass foobar.org
```

but this isn't working for me.  So what is a good way to set secret credentials that I don't want in my `repo/Jenkinsfile`

Comment: specify `is not working for me`

Comment: it's saying that credentials were not provided.  The same curl command works via command line, but the creds aren't being passed here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment variables in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130931/environment-variables-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Jenkins project with **Execute shell** build step. In that shell you can run curl command and to set credentials, there is one option named ***This build is parameterized***, where you can create **Password Parameter**. These parameters can be used in shell with curl command. Here is screenshot of my test project.
This way is secure because password is stored in encrypted format.

[image].