# Override system environment in node config

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to override TMPDIR for builds kicked off on one of my nodes.

I've added a new value in the node properties environment variables:

[image: Environment variables for node]

But when I run my job, TMPDIR is still set to the system value. ZIG does get set, however:

```
# Output from job running `env`
TMPDIR=/var/folders/nf/p0pz9cv93wz8m314wyk3yp_h0000gn/T/
ZIG=Zag
```

The same thing happens if I add the environment settings to the Jenkins master config. I can successfully use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to change it on each job, but we have a number of jobs and I would really prefer that it be a node configuration (the node has a dedicated build drive).

How can I override TMPDIR for all builds launched on this node?

I am using Jenkins 1.624 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the EnvInject plugin installed, which was [preventing the environment variables from being overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23550728/339378) (even though I wasn't using it, and it didn't work when I turned it on anyway).

I uninstalled that plugin and now my problem is gone.