# Set environment variable on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to execute on command on Jenkins shell.
Here is this command:

```
gits pull origin my-branch
```

Jenkins say me that command is not found.
`‘gits’` is a command that I build and group many repository.
In my local machine, I add the variable environment to run fine 'gits' on bash like this :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/blabla/folder_contain_gist_file_script
```

It works fine when I try to 'gits' branch on my terminal machine.
But on jenkins shell I got error.
I think that the trouble comes from the variable environment on jenkins.
So how to set jenkins environment variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [modify PATH variable in jenkins master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502306/modify-path-variable-in-jenkins-master)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the manage jenkins/configure system menu, did you try to add that:

[image]

[image]

If it doesn't work, you can try the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) (to overwrite the PATH variable at the job level).