# Jenkins does not recognize command sh?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to get a Jenkinsfile to work. 
I've been trying to run this test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
node {
    stage('Build') {
        echo 'Building....'
        // Create virtualenv
        sh 'echo "hi"'
    }
    stage('Test') {
        echo 'Building....'
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        echo 'Deploying....'
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error when trying to build:

```
Warning: JENKINS-41339 probably bogus PATH=/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/lib64/ccache:$PATH; perhaps you meant to use ‘PATH+EXTRA=/something/bin’?
[test-job-jenkinsfile-pipeline] Running shell script
nohup: failed to run command `sh': No such file or directory
```

I updated all the pipeline plugins to the latest version and still run into this error. Any help?

Comment: Heed the warning; you apparently did something to `PATH` so that Jenkins doesn't know where to look for `sh`.

Comment: Yeah I realized that at the end. I guess something happened when updating because the `PATH` was never touched. Deleting it fixed it.

Comment: >Deleting it fixed it.


What is _it_ here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So it seems the reason was that the global property `PATH` was causing the issue. By going to `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure System` and deleting the `PATH` global property solved my issue. See [JENKINS-41339](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41339).

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: Saviour .... !!!

Answer (score 53):

Jonathan's answer is correct in that modifying $PATH using the Jenkins Environment Variable settings causes this problem - but just deleting the PATH customizations you have will likely cause you to lose functionality, especially if you have any Freestyle type projects in your Jenkins.

See, in the entire rest of the universe it's very common to edit the $PATH by setting it to your new thing plus the existing $PATH, like this:

`PATH=/opt/blah/bin:$PATH`

This prepends `/opt/blah/bin` to what's already in `$PATH`. So the final `$PATH` might look like: `/opt/blah/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin` (this is just an example of course)

This actually works fine for Jenkins Freestyle projects. However, for Pipeline projects Jenkins for some reason does not actually evaluate and replace the $PATH variable in the variable you've set. So you literally end up with a path of `/opt/blah/bin:$PATH` - so nothing that was there before is still in your $PATH!

Apparently instead of just fixing that bug, Jenkins project decided to (1) detect the condition and display a weird warning ("Warning: JENKINS-41339 probably bogus") to imply you should check out that ticket and (2) create a brand new way of defining additions to PATH, which is the best solution to your problem because it allows you to customize the $PATH without breaking everything. You do this in Jenkins->Configure System.

- Define a variable called `PATH+EXTRA` where EXTRA can apparently be whatever.
- In that variable, just put your additions for the PATH. So in my example above, I would NOT set `PATH` at all, rather I'd just set:
  `PATH+EXTRA=/opt/blah/bin`
- Now remove any defined `PATH` variable.

According to a [related ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41492), this is documented somewhere in Jenkins, but is not documented in the place it needs to be, in Manage Jenkins->Configure System.

Comment: Just what I needed since I could not touch PATH in Configure System without breaking other jobs. `PATH+EXTRA=/usr/local/bin` worked!

Answer (score 19):

In order to fix this issue, in case that you can't delete the PATH global property from "**Manage Jenkins -> Configure System**", you should add the following step:

`withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'])`

Like following:
for Scripted Pipeline:

```
node {
  stage ('STAGE NAME') {
    withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']) {
      sh '//code block'
    }
  }
}
```

or for Declarative Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'master'
  }

  stages {
    stage ('STAGE NAME') {
      steps {
        withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']) {  
          sh '''
            //code block
          '''
        }
      }
    }
```

I hope this helps. I also struggled a lot to find a solution for this.

Comment: I think this would be a nice solution, you could also make this a bit more reusable by putting the `PATH+EXTRA=/usr...` in a variable at the top and reference that. Oh, and to add, this solution does NOT work for me :( I'm just getting the same error :/

Answer (score 4):

@XP84's solution worked for me. I was getting issue with running `python3` on a Mac Jenkins, I added this to environment variable and it started working. Here's a screenshot if anyone was like me and was having trouble inputting the actual values in respective fields.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins doesn't know what you mean by `sh`

```
nohup: failed to run command `sh': No such file or directory
```

This means the executable for your shell is not in your path.  Go to `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` scroll down until you find the section labelled Shell

[image: empty shell path in Jenkins]

Add the path to the executable you want to use for your shell when you call sh.  Alternatively make sure the location for the executable for sh is in the path being used by your Jenkins instance (which depending on other factors, may or may not be the same as the system path).

**Some examples**

On windows you might want `sh` to mean `powershell`*. You would do this by setting the shell path to point at powershell.

```
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

If you are on *nix Jenkins will probably default to use whatever shell sh is already defined as for the user Jenkins is running under, but you could specify the path to a particular shell so jenkins will always use that shell. For example to always run `sh` as bash one could specify

```
/bin/bash
```

---

*Given that Jenkins has specific build steps for windows batch and powershell commands I tend to think of the Shell specifically as a *nix style shell.  On a windows system you would need to install some sort of shell emulator, such as Cygwin.

Comment: Are there examples of what to put there? Sorry I'm kind of new to this and I did not setup the Jenkins. Also it was working previously before the plugins were updated, could the updated plugins have changed anything?

Comment: @JonathanWong It should be the location of the shell executable on your system.  That is going to be specific to what is installed on your system and what you want to use.  On windows you might want `sh` to mean powershell. You would set the path to powershell exe: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`   If you are on linux Jenkins will probably default to whatever `sh` is defined as for the user Jenkins is running under.  I think of the Shell as a *nix shell so on a windows system you would have to find such a shell for windows (Cygwin for instance) and point to that.

Comment: I tried typing in `/bin/bash` and it seems to recognize it since no error popped up when doing the configure. When trying to run the script it still produced the same no such directory error.

Comment: Thanks. For me I just needed to point it at Git bash's "sh", which I have installed on my machine. So in my case: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe"

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I did this.

1. **Remove Path variable from Jenkins Environment variables.**

[image]

2. **Added 'withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/opt/flutter/bin'])'  in my steps.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way to avoid this issue and also not deleting global PATH at `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` is to specify the `PATH` differently, apparently the following works fine and can append the `PATH` in the current environment

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment {
  PATH = "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
}
```

but the following results into `nohup: failed to run command sh': No such file or directory`

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment {
  PATH = "/usr/local/bin:${env.PATH}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins' most friendly and  simplest solution while dealing with environment variables is to use [Environment Injector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

so to fix this issue you just need to do the following:

1. Install Environment Injector Plugin
2. Open your pipeline and enable **Prepare an environment for the run** check box and add `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin` inside **Properties Content** text box.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above... but didn't work until I included in my steps `container()`. For some reason, when Jenkins is trying to run the `.sh` file it's trying on Jenkins master, even if my `agent` is set up:

```
agent {
    label "gen-java-slave"
}
```

Global pipeline environment block:

```
environment {
    PATH = "/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
}
```

Example of a working stage:

```
stage('Create a Dump for Senapt Arango DB') {
        steps {
            container('general-container-name') {
                withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/bin/arangodump']) {  
                    sh '''
                        ./backup-arango-senapt.sh
                    '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```