# Jenkins neo.sh not found error while using SAP Project Piper Library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, sap-project-piper

I am  setting up a CI/CD pipeline [scenario](https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/scenarios/ui5-sap-cp/Readme/) for SCP NEO environment based on the prebuilt pipeline on Project Piper. I tried to execute a pre-built library called Project Piper for Jenkins and I got the following error. The error seems neo.sh is not found. But I downloaded neo SDK and placed it in the neo-sdk folder. Also neo.sh is available inside `/opt/sap/neo-sdk/neo-java-web-sdk-3.39.10/tools` folder in linux.

Please see error in Jenkins

[image]

Please see .pipeline/config file where that location is referenced

```
steps: 
  mtaBui1d: 
    buildTarget: 'NEO' 
    mtaJarLocation: '/opt/sap/mta.jar' 
  neoDeploy: 
    neoHome: '/opt/sap/neo-sdk/'
    neo: 
      credentialsId: 'NEO DEPLOY'
      account: 
      host: 'hana.ondemand.com'
```

Docker is not used and I set-up Jenkins in ubuntu inside Vmware virtual machine. If the docker is not available, the library is capable of running locally in Jenkins server.

I am keeping neo-sdk tool in a local folder which contain neo.sh which is used to deploy application to SAP Cloud Platform. I am not writing any script my own as everything is prebuilt scripts from Project piper.

Comment: The first error in the first screenshot seems to be `docker: not found` - looks like Docker is either not installed or not accessible to Jenkins. Sometimes it helps to look for a line beginning with `+ ` which indicates a started command and try to run the same command in a similar environment to see what might be blocking it.

Comment: @V-R Docker is not used and I set-up Jenkins in ubuntu inside Vmware virtual machine.If the docker is not available,the library is capable of running locally in Jenkins server as seen below docker: not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved and thanks both of you for the same. I used envInjecter Plugin in Jenkins. Then go to manage jenkins->Configure->Set environment variables and set path as in
[image]

For more detail see the comment from XP84 in this StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987005/jenkins-does-not-recognize-command-sh)

Answer (score 0):

As already state in the [GH issue](https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/issues/1166#issuecomment-584869894) you should extend your `PATH` env var to also look inside `/opt/sap/neo-sdk/neo-java-web-sdk-3.39.10/tools`.

You do this by executing `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/sap/neo-sdk/neo-java-web-sdk-3.39.10/tools`.

Or an even better way would be to [symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-can-i-symlink-a-file-in-linux) the `neo.sh` into a folder that is already on the `PATH`.

With `echo $PATH` you can display the env var and have a look which directories are already exposed.

Comment: @Christopher.Thanks.Unable to access path  was the error