# Node not found on Jenkins docker instance

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

I am running Jenkins as a docker container, and have installed the [NodeJS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin) and followed thoroughly the setup instructions. When I try to run a script using `node`, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/jenkins9123978873441132802.sh: line 1: node: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I checked the docker volume, the `node` bin is where it should be and is executable is there and it works fine when I run it from my host server:

```
user@server:/data/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/latest/bin$ ./node --version
v9.2.0
```

I modified my build script to explore a bit further the problem:

```
echo $PATH

cd /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/latest/bin
ls -all
./node --version

node --version
npm --version
```

and look how strange this is:

```
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/release
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Adding all registry entries
copy managed file [Main config] to file:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/release@tmp/config69012336710357692tmp
[release] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6243047436861395796.sh
+ echo /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/latest/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/latest/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
+ cd /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/latest/bin
+ ls -all
total 34112
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins     4096 Nov 20 16:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 jenkins jenkins     4096 Nov 20 16:16 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins 34921762 Nov 14 20:33 node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins       38 Nov 20 16:16 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins       38 Nov 20 16:16 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ ./node --version
/tmp/jenkins6243047436861395796.sh: line 1: ./node: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The `node` executable is present, and it's executable (`+x`). The path is correctly set, but the build still fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the path to the node binary

> /data/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/latest/bin

Does not exist on your shell path.

You should [edit Jenkins' variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23550728/1790644) to adjust your PATH.

Comment: It does exist in the path. It is automatically set by the NodeJS plugin. I just updated my question with the actual script that is being run. `echo $PATH` shows that the path is indeed correct. When I `cd` into the directory where the `node` executable is, I can see that it is actually there when doing the `ls -all`. So, `./node` should work since I `cd`ed into the correct directory. Still, won't work.

Comment: If it is on the path, just try using `node` vs `./node`, you right though, this does look strange.

Comment: Yup, but since `node` points at `/data/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/latest/bin/node`, the behaviour is the same as `cd`ing into that directory and running `./node`. I just did that to make sure the problem wasn't coming from `$PATH`.