# Jenkins - Execute bash script to deploy application

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have one bash script which deploys the application inside JBoss9.
It's working fine When I runs bash script from ubuntu terminal using command  ./jbctl -c restart tail -f nohup.out;

But when I calls same bash script inside Jenkins - Build - Execute shell, it shows me various errors like

```
    ./jbctl: line 123: cat: command not found
    ./jbctl: line 123: grep: command not found
    ./jbctl: line 123: cut: command not found
    ./jbctl: line 123: sed: command not found
    ./jbctl: line 124: cat: command not found
/tmp/jenkins2547454576675677717.sh: line 10: tail: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Without this jbctl.sh file, application can't be initialised. As there are bash commands inside this ./jbctl.sh file, these are not executed inside Jenkins - Build - Execute shell.

[image]

Is there any other way to run this jbctl.sh script inside Jenkins? Actually this is bash script.

Comment: Did you execute it from your ubuntu, or from other Jenkins agent?
Also please ensure if you have the correct `$Path` variable in Jenkins (**Manage Jenkins** -> **Global Properties** -> **Environment variables** ).

Comment: I am doing execution from Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to your issue:

1. **Adjust Jenkins' environment variables** (prefered) as e.g. described at [wiki.jenkins.io](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project). In short: Navigate to `Manage Jenkins` > `Global Properties` > `Environment variables`. For more, see also SO: "[modify PATH variable in jenkins master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502306)"
2. **Quick'n'dirty**: Instead of `cat` use the full path of your command, e.g. `/usr/bin/cat`. You can determine this full path with entering `which cat` in your bash.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Your solution worked fine.