# docker: command not found ( mac mini ) only happens in jenkins shell step but work from command prompt

Tags: macos, jenkins, docker, docker-machine

I'm facing this weird problem , struggling to solve since almost couple of days.

**Working:**
On mac mini command prompt , I switch to jenkins user and can run docker command without any problem.

**Not Working:**
but when I run a jenkins job , inside shell command step docker is not recognized.

I'm getting error

```
docker: command not found

docker --version
```

But mentioning explicit path of docker , does work

```
/Users/buildserver/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker --version
```

Question : Why docker command can't look into correct path ?

Permissions

lrwxr-xr-x   1 buildserver  staff        71 Oct 14 10:44 docker -> /Users/buildserver/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker

jenkins uses is part of staff group.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vikram

Comment: Try echoing and verifying $PATH within the Jenkins job. It's most probably different than on your shell prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PATH` which Jenkins jobs start with isn't the same as the path which the Jenkins user sees in bash. In the Jenkins UI you can edit the environment varables (from Manage Jenkins/Configure System), and add the Docker folder to `PATH`:

```
PATH -> $PATH:/Users/buildserver/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/bin/
```

Some more detail in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818403/jenkins-hudson-environment-variables).

Comment: + echo '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/local:/Users/buildserver/Library/Group\' Containers/group.com.docker/bin/
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/local:/Users/buildserver/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/bin/
+ whoami
jenkins
+ docker --version
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson4594253879036703398.sh: line 4: docker: command not found

Comment: I got it fixed with PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/                      which docker 
/usr/local/bin/docker
/Users/buildserver/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin

Answer (score 47):

For others (Late but worthy), I installed Jenkins via Brew, so I add **Docker's path** to the file below:    ***/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.176.3/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist*** (Whole file looks like below)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/libexec/java_home</string>
      <string>-v</string>
      <string>1.8</string>
      <string>--exec</string>
      <string>java</string>
      <string>-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true</string>
      <string>-jar</string>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/libexec/jenkins.war</string>
      <string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>
      <string>--httpPort=8080</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true />
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/:/Users/Kh0a/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Then restart Jenkins' service:

```
brew services restart jenkins-lts
```

[More question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082747/8160903)

Comment: As mentioned by [Alexander Yalunin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7508493/alexander-yalunin) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58688597/11031425), the new directory in Mac should be `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.387.1/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`

Comment: `Kh0a` has to be replaced with the actual user in your machine - `/Users/{replace with your user}/Library/Group\ Containers`, or use env variable to grab it dynamically - `$USER`

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the above issue by updating the file

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.176.3/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist.
```

I have added the path of docker in the above file.

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
<string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/:/Users/admin/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker</string>
  </dict>
```

Comment: you may need to update `/Users/admin/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker ` => `/Users/${USER}/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker`. `${USER}` var may not get expanded in the plist. May need manual update there.