# Docker Image Build error on jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, macos, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

as a DevOps student I have issue that i couldn't fix

I have this repo
https://github.com/lethalfb/insurance

When i run pipeline on my linux machine , everything works great but i would like to run it on my mac m2 laptop and I am getting this error

```
+ docker build -t lethalfb/insure-me:3.0 --pull --no-cache .
/Users/lethal/.jenkins/workspace/web@2@tmp/durable-fc91d301/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
```

stage part

```
    
    stage('Docker Image Build'){
        echo 'Creating Docker image'
        sh "docker build -t $dockerHubUser/$containerName:$tag --pull --no-cache ."
```

I ve Docker Desktop install and tested with hello-world , works fine
chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock applied

Jenkins installed with all necessary plugins also maven, jdk, ansible etc.

Am I missing something here ?

It took long time otherwise i wouldn't disturb nobody

Thanks for help

[jenkins errorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4csAn.png)
[jenkins error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjvMw.png)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40043325/6727228

Comment: i appreciate for help

Answer (score 0):

It could be multiple things; like @Ruslan suggested; it might be an [incomplete PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043004/docker-command-not-found-mac-mini-only-happens-in-jenkins-shell-step-but-wo/40043325#40043325) (of the user running Jenkins / Jenkins Agent).

- You are allowed to *echo* the [environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/): `sh 'printenv'` (Should contain PATH)
- You are allowed to *echo* current $PATH directly `echo "PATH is: ${env.PATH}"`
- You are allowed to (tmp!) [append/adjust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237051/how-to-set-path-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline) the $PATH within the pipeline

Other possibilities:

- The user running Jenkins / the pipeline has no access to docker, due to docker not being installed for *other* users (You can get the user running the pipeline/script via: `sh 'whoami'`)
- [Jenkins Agent(s)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/), if used (Alternative to "build-in node(s)"), can be launched as physical machines, virtual machines, Kubernetes clusters, and with Docker images; be extra sure that with the latter two the agent image used "*contains*" docker

Comment: i appreciate for help