# Environment variable not seen from Jenkins Pipeline scrit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In "**Manage Jenkins**" -> "**Configure System**" -> "**Global properties**", I added:

```
Name:  git
Value: /path/to/my/git
```

and:

```
Name: PATH+git
Value: /path/to/my/git
```

However, if I try `sh("git status")` from a Jenkins pipeline, I get:

`git: command not found`

While if I try with the full path `sh("/path/to/my/git status")`, git is seen.

Any idea why `git` is not seen in a Jenkins Pipeline Script after being declared as an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use variable reference in your sh step:

```
sh '$git status'
```

Note the single quotes, this is so that groovy doesn't interpret the `$` as an variable reference (leave it up to sh). If you use double quotes, then you have to escape the dollar sign:

```
sh "\$git status"
```

or you can access the environment directly in groovy:

```
sh "${env.git} status"
```

Comment: Is there a way to make `git`be seen as the environment variable? There is a script that calls `git` directly, which I can not modify.

Comment: I would suggest that you modify the PATH variable and append your path to git at the **start** of the path variable, e.g. `/path/to/my/git:$PATH`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5819768/7509826