# aws command not found error even after installing aws cli on jenkins windows slave when running a jenkins job

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cli, aws-cloudformation

I have installed [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on my `windows` slave in `Jenkins`. To verify the same, I run the following command in the command line of the windows machine and get this as the output

```
C:> aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.122 Python/2.7.9 Windows/2008ServerR2 botocore/1.5.85
```

I am running an [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command in the execute windows batch command in the  jenkins job and the job is failing for the following reason

```
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\hudson1929374596375903011.sh: line 6: 
aws: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

The `aws` command I am running is

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://file1.json
```

I also checked the `PATH` variable on the windows machine and it contains `AWSCLI` path.

My goal is to run [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command via Jenkins job. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You may need to explicitly set your jenkins PATH. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473479/how-to-set-the-path-environment-variable-in-jenkins-configuration-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that Jenkins has a different `%PATH%` than when you are logged in.

Try finding your path via jenkins. Create a job and in the script that runs echo out your %PATH% to see what jenkins' thinks your path is.

You can modify Jenkins' environment variables, including `%PATH%`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819768/8207662

Comment: Yes you were right. AWS CLI was not present in the %PATH% Variable. Just add the following link in your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818403/jenkins-hudson-environment-variables 
So that I can accept the same